# Let $f(x)=a_0^2x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+a_2x^{n-2}+...........+a_n,\,$ where $a_0,a_1,....,a_n \in \Bbb R$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was stuck on the following problem which I came across during my study of theory of equations:

> Let $f(x)=a_0^2x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+a_2x^{n-2}+...........+a_n,\,$ where the coefficients $a_0,a_1,....,a_n$ are real. If $\,\xi\,$ be greater than any of the real roots of the equation $f(x)=0,\,$ then I have to show that $\,f(\xi)\,$ is positive.

<s>In the question it was given that $f(x)=a_0^2x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+.....+a_n$, I am not sure whether it would be $f(x)=a_0x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+.....+a_n$</s> .

Can someone give explanation about how to tackle it? Thanks and regards to all.

Comment: The reason it's $a_0^2$ is to ensure that the leading coefficient is positive. That observation should crack the problem for you.

Comment: The coefficient of $x^n$ tells you what happens when $x\to +\infty$.

Comment: Yes .I see that $f(x)  \to +\infty \,\,\text{as}\,\, x \to +\infty$  but still I am not sure how to utilize this information to crack the problem.

Comment: @learner Also, "If $\xi$ be greater than any of the real roots".

Comment: Well it means that you end in the positives but if you were in the negatives after the last root, how would you get up there?

Comment: @learner, When you change $x$, $f(x)$ cannot change sign except at the real roots of $f(x)$. If $\xi$ is greater than any of the real roots, its sign will be the same as the one we get when we send $x \to \infty$. Since $a_0^2 > 0$, the sign for large positive $x$ is positive.

Comment: Counterexample: $n=2, a_0=0, a_1=-1, a_2=1, \xi=2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x)=a_0^2x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+.....+a_n$

What do you know about $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}f(x)$?

> You know that $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=+\infty$. Now try using the definition of the limit to show you have a number so that at all the numbers greater than that number, the function is positive.

-

> If you use the definition of the limit, you get $\forall A \in \Bbb R, \exists x_0 \in \Bbb R,\forall x \ge x_0, f(x)\ge A $. Now take $A=1$. You have $x_0\in \Bbb R$ so that $\forall x \ge x_0, f(x) \ge 1>0$. What do you know about $f(\xi)$ and what are the two possible cases?

-

> Since we know $f(\xi)\not= 0$, either $f(\xi)>0$ or $f(\xi)<0$. Is one of those impossible? If yes, you could try to prove it can't be by supposing it is true a finding a contradiction.

-

> Suppose we had $f(\xi)<0$. If $\xi \ge x_0$, $f(\xi)>0$ which is absurd so $\xi < x_0$. Since $f$ is continuous, $\xi<x_0$ and $f(\xi)<0<f(x_0)$, by the intermediate value theorem, we have $x_1 \in (\xi,x_0)$ so that $f(x_1)=0$ so we have a root of $f$ bigger than $\xi$ which is absurd by the definition of $\xi$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation.Got it...